# Math, largest number

Tags: c#, math

does anyone know of a Math method that returns the largest number of a 
   given number of digits.

e.g The largest number using **1 digit is 9, 2 is 99, 3 is 999, 4 is 9999** .... and so on.

It is easily achievable using strings however this is not quite 
   what I am looking for.

```
  private double GetLargestNumber(int numOfDigits)
    {
        string max = "";
        for (int i = 1; i <= numOfDigits; i++)
        {
            max += "9";
        }
        return Convert.ToDouble(max);

    }
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: By the way, if you ever want to build a string of digits you can just use `new string('9', numOfDigits)`

Answer (score 17, accepted):

```
return Math.Pow(10, numOfDigits) - 1;
```

Comment: Thanks Marc, much appreciated

Comment: bdares, if numOfDigits == 1, Math.Pow(10, numOfDigits + 1) - 1 would be 99, because 10 on the power of 2 is 100, so your comment is incorrect. Marc Gravell's solution is correct, +1 for him.

Comment: @Marc, great solution, only problem is once it hits 16 digits it doens't work. 16 digits returns: 10000000000000000

Comment: @hareg indeed, there is a problem with the OP choosing to use double arithmetic. That is unlikely to be an issue in most common cases, but well noted. Building manually in a loop with `long` would be a fix, but only buys a few more digits (not many)

Comment: Thanks to all for your input, I'll go with Marc's solution

Answer (score 0):

Depending on the Max number of digits you want to past to the method you might need to cast the return to allow for more than 15 digits.

```
return (UInt64)Math.Pow(10, numOfDigits) - 1)
```

The above would allow upto 19. using a "Double" would only work upto 15 digits.